# How do I return JSON response in Class based views, instead of HTTP response

Tags: python, json, django, ajax, django-views

I have a class based view. I am using Ajax on a bootstrap modal. To avoid page refresh, I want to return JSON response instead of HTTP response with this class based view- but I have only seen how to return JSON response for function based views.

**views.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class TaskCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'create.html'
    form_class = TaskForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('task_list')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update(user=self.request.user)
        return kwargs
```

Comment: Override the **`post(...)`** method of CBV

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try code below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.http import JsonResponse

class TaskCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'create.html'
    form_class = TaskForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('task_list')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update(user=self.request.user)
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return JsonResponse({'foo':'bar'})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:** works for me. actually you have to override the post method if you are stick with Class-based Views.

```
import json

class TaskCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = TaskForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('task_list')

...

def post(self, request, **kwargs):
     response_data = 'your data'

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),content_type="application/json")
```