# Return JsonResponse in Class-based CreateView

Tags: json, django, api

I'm using `curl` to submit form data to my website.

```
curl -F some_file=@file.txt -F name=test_01 https://localhost:8000
```

It's not an API but I have a requirement for a single endpoint that behaves as an API. I'm a little out of my depth here, so I'm hoping someone can help me.

I've got the model set up and working and the `CreateView`, as well:

```
class CreateFile(CreateView):
    model = SomeFile
    fields = ['name', 'some_file', . . .]
```

When I send a POST request with `curl` as above to the specified URL (`/file/request`), the object is created in the DB and I get a response (eg, `/thanks` now which is an HTTP response from template view). But since a non-browser will be sending this request, I was hoping to respond with some JSON. Maybe with the object's name, status, etc.

I've tried a few things with mixed results... For example, if I use `View` instead of `CreateView`, I can return JSON but I really like the ease and convenience of the `CreateView` CBV, so I'm hoping I can do what I want this way.

How can I do this? I found a SO question that gave some clues: [How do I return JSON response in Class based views, instead of HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59645540/how-do-i-return-json-response-in-class-based-views-instead-of-http-response)

But this deals with the typical form/view model in the browser. If I have to override the `post` method, what's the best way to get the form data so I can create the object? Do I need a form class even though I'm not processing a rendered form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with something from the Django docs:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

class JSONResponseMixin:
    """
    A mixin that can be used to render a JSON response
    """
    def render_to_json_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        return JsonResponse(self.get_data(context), **response_kwargs)

    def get_data(self, context):
        return context
```

Then I used this in a `DetailView`, overriding both get and post methods.

```
class FileRequest(JSONResponseMixin, DetailView):

    def get:
        . . .
        return self.render_to_response(response_data)

    def post:
        . . .
        return self.render_to_response(response_data)

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        return self.render_to_json_response(context, **response_kwargs)
```